# Не могу получить данные из iframe

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

Суть задания: создать два фрейма. В одном - анимация (webm), в другом - ссылка. Когда курсор над ссылкой, то начинается подсчёт количества анимаций.
**Проблема** в том, что я получаю либо фрейм, к которому нельзя применить соответствующие функции для манипулирования с видео, либо null, пытаясь "достать" из фрейма видео.

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
    </head>

    <body>
        <iframe src="video.html" id="framevideo" width="500" height="280" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>
        <br>
        <iframe src="link.html" id="framelink" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            // let count = 0;
            // let timerId = 0;

            // let link = document.getElementById('framelink'); // в переменной сам фрейм
            // let video = document.getElementById('framevideo'); // в переменной сам фрейм, а не видео
            // ==========================
            // let iframeVideo = document.getElementById('framevideo');
            // let video = iframeVideo.contentWindow.document.getElementsByTagName('video');
            // Uncaught DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin "null" from accessing a cross-origin frame. at <anonymous>:2:39


            // link.onmouseover = function(event)
            // {
            //     // здесь выполняются функции load(), play(), ... к видео
            // }

            // link.onmouseout = function(event)
            // {
            //     // здесь выполняются функции load(), play(), ... к видео
            // }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**video.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
    </head>

    <body>
        <video src="video/video.webm" id="video" muted="muted"></video>
    </body>
</html>
```

**link.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
    </head>

    <body>
        <a href="" id="link">Тык</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Если вы делаете это не на сайте, а просто в локальном файле, то подобные манипуляции с локальными файлами запрещены в целях безопасности

Comment: Да, в локальном файле. Есть ли какая-нибудь альтернатива с использованием iframe в соответствии с заданием?

Comment: @fiwila7945, рекомендую поднять локальный сервер. Чтоб адрес сайта начинался не с file:///, а http://

Comment: Если вы начинающий и у вас Windows - рекомендую OpenServer

Comment: А есть ещё варианты? В локальном файле, без создания локальных серверов.